# Conditional Lag from T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, apache-spark, conditional-statements, lag, partition

I'm trying to migrate some code from Transact-SQL from Azure Stream Analytics to a local environment, by now I tried pyspark but with any results that satisfies the requirements. The problem is that we can't put a *when* clause on the *over*. I would like to do this in pyspark or any language that is open source. Preferably a streaming processing

As input data I have something like this:

```
ID_PAINEL  STATE      ID_EVENT_LOG
------------------------------
2          LIGADO     40
1          LIGADO     50
1          SOMETHING  
1          TEST  
1          DESLIGADO  
1          LIGADO     60
1          SOMETHING  
1          TEST
2          SOMETHING    
2          TEST  
3          SOMETHING
3          TEST
```

The code that I have on Azure Stream Analytics:

```
[arranq_disp_unique] AS (SELECT *, CASE
                                WHEN  LAG(ID_EVENT_LOG) OVER (PARTITION BY ID_PAINEL LIMIT DURATION(minute, 10) WHEN STATE LIKE 'LIGADO%') is null then id_painel
                                ELSE LAG(ID_EVENT_LOG) OVER (PARTITION BY ID_PAINEL LIMIT DURATION(minute, 10) WHEN STATE LIKE 'LIGADO%') 
                                END AS UNIQUE_PAR
                            FROM [classify_reconnection_success]
```

**Expected output:**

[image]